# Replace all Special Characters including space with - using C#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to replace all `Special Characters` which can't be parse in `URL` including space, double space or any big space with '-' using C#.

I don't want to use any Parse Method like `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode`.
How to do this ? I want to include any number of space between two words with just one '-'.
For example, if string is `Hello# , how are you?`
Then, Result should be, `Hello-how-are-you`, no '-' if last index is any special character or space.

Comment: but what if 2 or more special characters is there in between 2 words ? I want to replace it just by one '-'

Comment: Yes hence the `+` quantifier meaning match `1` or more times..

Comment: @hwnd, which is the perfect regex to match all special characters (which can't be parse in URL) and space ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 string str = "Hello# , how are you?";
 string newstr = "";
 //Checks for last character is special charact
 var regexItem = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]+");
 //remove last character if its special
 if (regexItem.IsMatch(str[str.Length - 1].ToString()))
 {
   newstr =   str.Remove(str.Length - 1);            
 }
 string replacestr = Regex.Replace(newstr, "[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+", "-");
```

**INPUT:**
Hello# , how are you?

**OUTPUT:**
Hello-how-are-you

**EDIT:**
Wrap it inside a class

```
   public static class StringCheck
        {
            public  static string Checker()
            {
                string str = "Hello# , how are you?";
                string newstr = null;
                var regexItem = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]+");
                if (regexItem.IsMatch(str[str.Length - 1].ToString()))
                {
                    newstr = str.Remove(str.Length - 1);
                }
                string replacestr = Regex.Replace(newstr, "[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+", "-");
                return replacestr;
            }

        }
```

and call like this,

```
 string Result = StringCheck.Checker();
```

Comment: Thank you, As I think, it will solve my issue. But, I have one query. I have created method for this and returning final string. And I want to call it in eval, so I am using it like `Class.Method(String Value)`, But it not returning anything. Can u help me for that ?

Comment: @JeetenParmar Try to accept the answer hereafter, your history shows you never accept the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

You need two steps to remove last special character and to replace all the remaining one or more special characters with `_`

```
public static void Main()
{
  string str = "Hello# , how are you?";
  string remove = Regex.Replace(str, @"[\W_]$", "");
  string result = Regex.Replace(remove, @"[\W_]+", "-");
  Console.WriteLine(result);
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/YBjL5A)

Answer (score -1):

```
string[] arr1 = new string[] { " ", "@", "&" };

newString = oldString;
foreach repl in arr1
{
    newString= newString.Replace(repl, "-");
}
```

Of course you can add into an array all of your spec characters, and looping trough that, not only the " ".

More about the replace method at the following [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I am already using this, but I dint find it proper solution so I want any efficient solution.